# data in reverse sort order in FirestoreRecyclerAdapter using StaggeredGridLayoutManager?

Tags: android, firebase, staggeredgridlayoutmanager

> I am using Firebase as a backend for my notes making Android application and using "FirestoreRecyclerAdapter" for fetching the data from it. I want that data in reverse sorted order.

> How can I achieve this using the FirestoreRecyclerAdapter?

> ```
> database = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
> reference = database.collection("users").document(currentUserId).collection("notes");
> query = reference.orderBy("lastUpdated");
> ```

> this query fetch data in sorted order in

> ```
> StaggeredGridLayoutManager layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, 1);
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Query.Direction.DESCENDING to sort in descending order in java;

```
query = reference.orderBy("lastUpdated",Query.Direction.DESCENDING);
```